# OpenLDAP- an attribute to store UUIDs

Tags: openldap

Basically, I would like to create a custom unique identifier for users and store then in OpenLDAP.

Is there an attribute in OpenLDAP that can be used to store UUID numbers?

Answer (score 0):

[entryUUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4530) is generated server side for each object in OpenLDAP.

Apparently [it can be modified by a client](https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201305/msg00238.html) if you really want to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it OK to modify the entryUUID attribute or OpenLDAP uses it internally?